# Design a library management database

Tags: database

I'm designing a library management database, i'm stuck on should i separate library resources(e.g. Books, Videos, Audios) to three tables or only one table contains all resources information, it's because most of the columns of them are same.

```
**Books**
id
title
author
isbn
...
```

---

```
**Audios**
id
title
author
isbn
duration
...
```

---

```
**Videos**
id
title
author
isbn
duration
cast
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the common columns in a single table and separate them based on a type:

```
library_items {id, type_id, title, author, isbn}
item_types {id, name}
```

The type table would contain Book, Audio, Video.

Then having additional tables that contain the additional columns:

```
library_audios (id, duration}
library_videos {id, duration, cast}
```

Comment: But if i want to query something, i need to query data from two tables. Is that good?

Comment: Yep, if your database is a relational database system, like MySQL; PostgreSQL; or Oracle, then it is optimized to make these connections.

Answer (score 0):

please made the separate table for books, multimedia...
for books --- category then sub-category, category sr no -for books

for cd/dvd  type audio/ video .... it will much more help full for filter the data... ease to database access